# Override "Click to Call"

Tags: notifications, facetime, continuity

I'm using the latest High Sierra.
When using 3rd-party software to quickly place calls, like the Uni Call Alfred workflow or Cardhop, a notification pops requesting me to confirm or deny the call about to be placed. It beats the whole point of those clicks-saving apps.

Is there any way to disable this pop-up and simply go on with the call?
Or, at least, moving focus to that notification so I can act with my keyboard, without having to drag my pointer all the way to the top right corner.

It happens either with regular calls using iPhone and Continuity or FaceTime audio/video calls. Interestingly, this confirmation dialog does not appear when making calls with FaceTime directly.

[image]

Comment: That's probably a security measure to prevent 3rd party apps from making calls without you noticing it.

Comment: I really like those alerts in practice - the point of click to call is not having to mess with digits and it gives me time to line up my headset, etc.., but I understand you want your click to be the final go - just not everyone will share that preference. Let’s see if anyone can help you with a setting to disable that.

Comment: The similar risk applies to text messages as well yet there's no such security mechanism in that case. @bmike I understand, but when I'm invoking the call I'm already ready for it. Besides, when using FaceTime directly to make the calls, this confirmation dialog does not pop. I hope someone here would at least reveal a way to move the focus to this dialog, with the keyboard.